# Smart columns with CSS3

Tags: html, css

I have some text in a `<pre>` that is almost doing what I want with `column-count` and media queries.

http://jsfiddle.net/tbhtrL0f/11/ (change the size of the result pane to see 1/2/3 columns)

There are a couple of things I would like to change about this but don't know how:

1. Instead of doing the number of columns based on a media query, I would rather add a new column when there is sufficient horizontal space to do so (without overflow).
2. I would like to preferentially break where there are two returns in a row.

Are either/both of these changes possible with pure CSS?

Comment: Might be just me, but I am unable to view your fiddle.

Comment: thanks for trying, jsfiddle is slow today, it seems. I can load this after a while though: http://jsfiddle.net/tbhtrL0f/11/ hrm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question is doable, but the second would require some markup.

1. You can set the column width instead: `column-width: 20em` (or which ever width that suits your design). Doing so means that the column will be at least that wide (unless the containing block is even narrower), and new columns will be added as needed as long as they fit at that minimum measure. So no media queries needed. You could also combine `column-width`and `column-count`, which means that the column count is the maximum number of allowed columns. Finally, there's the `columns` shorthand, that allows you to set both at the same time: `columns: 20em 4;`
2. There's the `break-before`/`break-after` and `break-inside` properties, and they can be applied to *elements* within a column layout, but not to whitespace. I'd use JS to detect some certain kind of whitespace and inject something to break on. Also, if I remember correctly, the column break properties aren't that widely supported, but I can't find a link on that right now..

Comment: Good info, thanks. Browser support doesn't matter. Targeting ~latest Chrome and FF. Working on anything else would just be gravy.

Comment: I've calculated that the `em` width of the given text is `36`, for 61 columns. Any idea how I would calculate the width of the longest line in ems? http://jsfiddle.net/tbhtrL0f/13/

Comment: @SkylarSaveland: I'm not quite sure I follow... Do you mean that your optimum line-length is 61 characters? If so, there's not really a way to do that precisely, it depends on the font and rendering... I think trial and error is the way to go. Then there's the `ch` unit, but it has about 0 support... :-( http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#ch-unit

Comment: The actual text is dynamic, so we don't know ahead of time if we will have a song with 61 columns being the max. For part one of the question, I settled on this: https://github.com/pdh/meltodies/blob/master/js/melt.coffee#L129  `Math.round(_.max(scope.song_data.split("\n")).length * .69)`. It's brittle in that different browsers might break it, a change of fonts would definitely break it, etc. But, good enough for now. I'll have to look into `break-*` later - what you describe seems like the right approach though.